# How to automatically choose the latest version of a package

Tags: apt, software-installation

Some packages have the newest release as the default which excludes the version number from its name. e.g php

`$ apt-cache search php*-fpm --names-only`

`php-fpm - server-side, HTML-embedded scripting language (FPM-CGI binary) (default)
php7.0-fpm - server-side, HTML-embedded scripting language (FPM-CGI binary)`

This isn't the case for all packages and i would like to run a bash function which will automatically select the newest based on its naming convention.

For example if I wanted to install the latest version of the `oracle-java-installer` I would do the following.

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java -y && sudo apt-get update`

`aptget install oracle-java*-installer`

My aptget function works like so.

I have a regular expression which should search the `apt-cache` and retrieve the following four results.

```
oracle-java7-installer - Oracle Java(TM) Development Kit (JDK) 7
oracle-java6-installer - Oracle Java(TM) Development Kit (JDK) 6
oracle-java8-installer - Oracle Java(TM) Development Kit (JDK) 8
oracle-java9-installer - Oracle Java(TM) Development Kit (JDK) 9
```

`oracle-java9-installer` would be pulled from the results and `apt-get install` run using the package name.

The regex I am using is working correctly here [Regex](https://regex101.com/r/kufEio/1) but I haven't been able to escape it correctly so that it works in the terminal.

I am also yet to work out how to pull the latest package name from the `apt-cache search` results

```
function aptget(){

    pkg="$2"
    # versionRegex="(\d+\.)?(\d+\.)?(\d+)?"
    result="${pkg/\*/$versionRegex}"

    pkg_list=$(apt-cache search --names-only "^$result$")

    echo $pkg_list

    # pkg=

    set -- "${@:1:1}" "$pkg" "${@:3}"
    sudo apt-get "$@"
}
```

I would like help getting the regex to work in bash and any input on how to get the retrieve the name of the newest package only.

Answer (score 1):

This is a pretty bad idea. The naming convention is in place to avoid breaking things between mayor versions.

Every distribution needs specific versions of some mayor software; if you were to replace python 2.x with python3 your system would become unusable, possibly in a non-recoverable way.

Comment: I have a `vagrant_provision.sh` file which I want to have all the latest versions (if possible), there are some packages which I will probably need to hard code but until I run the VM i wont know. The function does not go anything i wouldn't do myself, it just prevents me from having to do a lookup of the apt-cache and finding the package name before hard coding it.

Answer (score 0):

```
function apt-get-latest(){
    set -- "${@:1:1}" "$(apt-cache-search-latest $2)" "${@:3}"
    sudo apt-get "$@"
}

function apt-cache-search-versions(){
    pkg="$1"
    prefix=${pkg%\**}
    suffix=${pkg#*\*}
    echo "$(apt-cache search --names-only "^$prefix*" | awk '{ print $1 }' | sort | grep -P ^$prefix'(\d+\.)?(\d+\.)?(\d+|)'$suffix$)"
}
function apt-cache-search-latest(){
    echo "$(apt-cache-search-versions $1 | tail -1)"
}
```

Usage

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java -y 
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php -y
sudo apt-get update

apt-cache-search-versions php*-fpm 
=> php5.6-fpm php7.0-fpm php7.1-fpm php-fpm

apt-cache-search-versions oracle-java*-installer 
=> oracle-java6-installer oracle-java7-installer oracle-java8-installer oracle-java9-installer


apt-cache-search-latest php*-fpm 
=> php-fpm

apt-cache-search-latest oracle-java*-installer 
=> oracle-java9-installer


apt-get-latest install php*-fpm
apt-get-latest install oracle-java*-installer
```